# Table with and link format for pandas style formatting

Tags: python, pandas

Here's the call I'm making on df, a pandas.DataFrame:

```
df.style.set_table_styles([
    dict(selector="tr", props=[
        ("background-color", "black"),
        ("color", "lawngreen"),
        ("border-color", "white")]),
    dict(selector="td", props=[
        ("text-align", "center")])]).render()
```

Everything above seems to be working. What I *can't* figure out is:

1. How to govern the width of the entire table
2. How to format `<a href...>` tags (without needing to format them individually, if this is even possible)

[The documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html#Table-Styles) discusses table-wide styles, but I haven't been able to find one that works. I've tried [set_table_attributes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_table_attributes.html) using `width="200px"`, but [it looks like](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_width.asp) HTML5 doesn't support that tag (and indeed that doesn't work either).

Is there a way to accomplish either or both of these?

Comment: Have you tried something like: `.set_table_attributes('style="width: 200px;"')` ?

Comment: Jon, that worked.